# How does lexical scoping with recursive iterators work?

Tags: recursion, iterator, lexical-scope

This particular example function is in Lua, but I think the main concepts are true for any language with lexical scoping, first-class functions, and iterators.

Code Description (TL;DR -- see code):

The code below defines an iterator constructor which merely defines a local value and returns an iterator function.

This iterator function, when run, uses the local value from the constructor and increases that value by 1. It then runs itself recursively until the value reaches 5, then adds 1 to the value and returns the number 5. If it's run again, it will run itself recursively until the value reaches 20 or higher, then it returns nil, which is the signal for the loop to stop.

I then run an outer loop using the iterator provided by the constructor, which will run the body of the loop when the iterator returns a value (5). In the body of the outer loop I put an inner loop that also uses an iterator provided by the constructor.

The program should run the body of the loop once (when the value in the outer loop iterator hits 5) and then run the inner loop completely (letting the inner loop value hit 20), then return back to the outer loop and run it until it finishes.

```
    function iterConstr()
        local indexes = {0}
        function iter()
            print(indexes[1])
            indexes[1] = indexes[1] + 1
            if indexes[1] == 5 then
                indexes[1] = indexes[1] + 1
                return 5
            elseif indexes[1]>=21 then
                print("finished!")
                return nil
            else
                print("returning next one")
                return iter()
            end
        end
        return iter
    end

    for val in iterConstr() do
        for newVal in iterConstr() do

        end
        print("big switch")
    end
```

The behavior I did not expect is that the value from the inner loop and outer loop seem to be linked together. When focus is returned to the outer loop after running through the inner loop, it runs with the expected next value for the outer loop (6), but then instead of iterating and incrementing up to 20, it instead jumps immediately to 21, which is where the inner loop ended!

Can anyone help explain why this bizarre behavior occurs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe your problem lies on line 3 - you declare `iter` as a global function instead of a local one, which makes it accessible from any Lua chunk. Changing that line to `local function iter()` corrects this behaviour. I think therefore that this is more of an issue with the developer applying lexical scoping than with lexical scoping itself :)

Comment: I had no idea that functions could be local as well. Thank you! For future readers, an explanation can be found here: https://www.lua.org/pil/6.2.html